# emerging variants

Tags: present-participles

In the following sentence, is the Delta variant an **emerging** one?

> The COVID-19 pandemic is increasingly becoming an arms race among the **emerging variants** of the virus, and at the moment, there is no question which one is winning: **the Delta variant** . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deduce that delta variant is an emerging variant.

We are told that there is an "arms race among the emerging variants",  So any competitor in that race must be an "emerging variant", in particular the "one [that] is winning" is an "emerging variant", so "the Delta variant is an emerging variant"

Comment: What's odd is that, although the sentence says the Delta variant is an emerging variant, actually it isn't. It has emerged already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The pronoun "one" refers to the only plural noun antecedent: "emerging variant of the virus". The specified one is identified as the Delta variant, so it must be one of the emerging variants.